# Function keys not working?

Tags: netbook, function-keys

I have a Toshiba NB205 netbook that is a few weeks old. Certain functions are controlled with function keys: `FN`+`ESC` toggles the mute, `FN`+`F8` toggles wireless, etc.

But now the key combinations are totally unresponsive. `ALT`+`F4` works fine, but `FN`+ anything fails silently. What could be the problem? Did this somehow get disabled? How else can I turn off wireless?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

If Fn lock isn't the culprit, reinstall the **[Toshiba Value Added Package (TVAP)](http://www.csd.toshiba.com/cgi-bin/tais/support/jsp/modelContent.jsp?ct=DL&os=&category=&moid=2464761&rpn=PLL28U&modelFilter=NB205-N230&selCategory=3&selFamily=2336267)**, it is responsible for the ACPI functionality of the netbook.

Answer (score 1):

The FN stuff is controlled by the BIOS, meaning that it's not controlled by Windows.
Some things to try:

1. Search in the BIOS for an option to
   re-activate it.
2. Try Fn+Numlock or Fn+Shift+Numlock

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it following these steps:

1. Download these prgrams from http://www.csd.toshiba.com and install them:

   ```
   ConfigFree for Windows 7
   Atheros Wireless LAN Driver for Windows 7
   ```
2. Restart flash cards:

   ```
   Start -> All Programs -> TOSHIBA -> Utilities -> Restart flash cards
   ```
3. Press <kbd>Fn</kbd>, the Fn functions to switch on or off will appear on your screen.

NOTE: When you need to switch it again you will need to restart flash cards.

Answer (score 0):

Disabling the wireless adapter in the OS would be the easiest.  If you don't plan on using it, probably in the BIOS.

**EDIT:** Sounds like your problem is <kbd>Fn</kbd> button quit working.  <strike>I don't know if that can be remapped in the OS using [The Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx).</strike>

**EDIT:** I noticed in the BIOS of a laptop I had that there is a Fn key emulation feature.  In my paticular laptop I could make the external keyboard's <kbd>Scroll Lock</kbd> key act as the laptop's keyboard <kbd>Fn</kbd> key.  Parhaps this would work for you.